# Starting over with Ethereum wallet

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

I'm a complete beginner, but managed to download Mist.  It was downloading blocks quite slowly, and I got the message to install the latest version (9.1).  I uninstalled the previous one, and went ahead with 9.1.  However, now I can't get started as I had previously.  I'm getting the following message that I could not connect to the node:

Node type:  geth
Network:  main
Platform:  win32 (Architecture x64)

...flag provided but not defined:  -syncmode

Comment: flag provided but not defined means that geth does not understand one of your command line arguments.  What command line are you using?

Comment: This is just when I click the GUI.  I did, however type "geth console" at the command, and that seems to have gotten me past this issue.

Comment: syncmode is a command line parameter to geth.  you can start geth with `geth --syncmode "fast"` to speed up the download of the blockchain.

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue, this is a problem caused by previous installs of the Mist client.

After I uninstalled through Programs and Features (Win 7), and reinstalled Mist (0.9.3), it worked great.